# UIApplication openURL: doesn't work with relative URLs

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, nsurl, uiapplication

Here's the code:

```
NSURL *newsUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"/Document/News/1593" relativeToURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://exist.ru"]];

// Outputs "http://exist.ru/Document/News/1593"
NSLog(@"%@", [newsUrl absoluteString]);

// works
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[newsUrl absoluteString]]];

// doesn't work
//[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:newsUrl];
```

Is it Apple's bug?

Comment: `absoluteString` doesn't return exactly what's "in" the `NSURL`. You're probably trying to open the relative part of the URL. What's your error?

Comment: No error. Just nothing happens after the method call.

Comment: Did you ever figure out *why* this was happening? I'm experiencing exactly the same behaviour. It doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 2):

in my Xcode output for `NSLog(@"NEW %@", newsUrl)` where I declare `newUrl` as

```
NSURL *newsUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"/Document/News/1593" relativeToURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://exist.ru"]]:
```

`NSLog` output is

> `/Document/News/1593 -- http://exist.ru`

but for  `[newsUrl absoluteString]`

`NSLog` output is

> `http://exist.ru/Document/News/1593`

So I'd guess that `[URLWithString: relativeToURL:]` is giving you the URL in a different format. This is reason your result is invalid.

Comment: This is what I was trying to say, props for actually testing it.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to no longer be an issue in iOS 9.x.

For < iOS 9.x support, add this wonderfully useless step before the call to **openURL:**

```
//Construct your relative URL 
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"path/to/whatever" relativeToURL:
    [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.example.com"]];

//FIX
url = [NSURL URLWithString:url.absoluteString];
```

Answer (score -1):

Not real clear on what you're trying to accomplish, but if you want to programmatically build your URL's with potentially different hosts or paths, why not something like this:

```
NSURL *newsUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:
 [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",@"http://exist.ru",@"/Document/News/1593"]];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:newsUrl];
```

Comment: I've got one static host and many dynamic relative paths. I thought Apple introduced [NSURL URLWithString:relativeToURL:] so that people won't have to manually concatenate parts of the URL as NSString's. Obviously, I was wrong. I don't see any other use of relative NSURLs then. Anyone?